Given a matrix $H$ with full column rank and an positive definite matrix $W$, is $H^{*}WH$ positive definite?
Given a matrix $H$ with full column rank, I know that $H^{*}H$ would be positive definite, but if we add an positive definite matrix in the middle, would the result $H^{*}WH$ be positive definite, or at least invertible? Any guidance/hint is appreciated.

It is positive-definite. You can use the definition of positive-definiteness to prove it without much fuss.

Oh you are right. For all $x$,  $x^{}H^{}WHx = (Hx)^{*}WHx$ indeed > 0. My carelessness got the better of me. Thanks.

So as to not let your carelessness win out again, don't forget that you need $x^* H^* W H x > 0$ only for $x \neq 0$. The fact that $H$ has full column rank is important to establish $Hx \neq 0$ when $x \neq 0$.

Yes, both points occured to me some time after I commented. I have a bad habit of letting my mouth go ahead of my thoughts. Thx!
